# How are the distances to the most distant $\gamma$-ray bursts measured?

Tags: astronomy, distance

This question came to my mind when I read on [NASA's website](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/swift/bursts/farthest_grb.html) that an explosion (gamma ray burst, GRB 080913) took place 12.8 billion light years away from us. How do they measure such large distances?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24927/2451 and links therein.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you measure distance to stars within the galaxy?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14016/how-do-you-measure-distance-to-stars-within-the-galaxy)

Comment: Voting to leave open: certainly not a duplicate of "distances to stars within the galaxy" as the techniques required for this much larger distance are completely different. As to the other possible dup, this measurement uses a technique not mentioned in the answers to that other more general question. Will edit this question a bit to make the distinction more clear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is the distance to a $\gamma \mathrm{-ray}$ burst (GRB) measured in just a few days?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/63332/how-is-the-distance-to-a-gamma-mathrm-ray-burst-grb-measured-in-just-a-f)

Comment: @Kyle but what about the one I linked? Also, if the OP didn't just want GRB's, there's http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/70400/how-do-we-know-that-these-radio-bursts-are-from-billions-of-light-years-away for radio.

Comment: @ChrisWhite both questions happen to ask about different GRB whose distances were estimated using different techniques (I think the one from this question was from the end of the Ly-$\alpha$ forest, the other one is emission lines from the galaxy). Since they ask about specific objects (though not by name), I'm still leaning not dupe, but your link is certainly arguable.

Comment: @Kyle then retracted, but perhaps the question should give some hint that photo-z's were involved? Maybe with some quote from the article?

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean [12.8 **billion** light years away](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/swift/bursts/farthest_grb.html)?

If so, in this case the distance was estimated by measuring a rough spectrum for the GRB. The NASA article I've linked says:

> In certain colors, the brightness of a distant object shows a characteristic drop caused by intervening gas clouds. The farther away the object is, the longer the wavelength where this fade-out begins.

This technique is used where it's hard to get a detailed spectrum and calculate the red shift.

If you're asking a more general question then this is covered in the question [How is distance measured to far away stars and galaxies?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45232/how-is-distance-measured-to-far-away-stars-and-galaxies) and your question would be a duplicate.

Comment: So, in essence, this is a rather fuzzy redshift calculation?

Comment: @M.Herzkamp: yes, exactly.

Comment: @JohnRennie: yes sir i meant 12.8 billion light years. sorry for omitting billion there.

Comment: I think that characteristic drop would be the beginning of the "Lyman-$\alpha$ forest". So really this is a lower limit on the distance (which, at 12.8 Gly, still tells you it's pretty darn far away).

Answer (score 0):

For relatively close objects, the distance can be measured through measurements of parallax (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax ).

Comment: And also using Variable stars in a star cluster.

Comment: Note this was a reasonable answer to the question as stated at the time of the answer (I almost downvoted until I noticed).